# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 Azure Cognitive-Speech To Text

Tags: ios, swift, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I have integrated [Speech SDK](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-iOS/issues/44) in my swift project successfully, but after integration when trying to run project in simulator then it is showing this errors but working fine if i run in device. Any help on what i should do to make it compatible for simulator also ?
[image]

I tried several ways by changing in Valid Architecture and Build Active Architecture Only... But no one works for me.
Please suggest me how can i solve this.

Comment: Can you please provide information about which device you were using and which simulator you are trying to use?

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic My app is for iPad only. I have an iPad mini and this error is same for all iPad simulator.

Comment: ok ill download the sdk and give it a try later

Comment: @MarcioRomeroPatrnogic Have you checked it ?